# Display RTF (RichText Format) From Database to Client Side Report (MS ReportViewer)

Tags: .net, reporting, reportviewer, rtf, richtext

Is this possible? I have been searching for a way to do this but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I have read somewhere that it isn't supported and then I've also read somewhere else that it is supported as of VS 2010, which is what I am using. I've heard Crystal Reports supports RTF but I seriously can't stand working with Crystal Reports any longer. It's so damn messy. What I don't understand the most though, is how an application like MS Access can display RTF on a report yet Win Forms can't?

Comment: Do you want to integrate this with another system or are you looking for an stand alone solution?

Comment: Standalone solution. I've noticed the richtextbox format in VBA for Access actually stores the data as HTML. I have no idea why, but the richtextbox in WinForms will not display HTML, so I would have to use a webbrowser control to do so but there's no way to save what's pasted into the richtextbox in winforms as HTML in the database since it uses actual RTF format, which is fine, but a report is unable to display RTF as far as I know....

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), it's a standalone reporting tool, and it can display RTF and HTML text directly from your database, just add a rich text control to the report and bind it to the field that contains rich text.

Comment: And you forgot to wrote it's not free.